# SVN + script to export files in windows

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

There are many scripts available to export files from SVN. But all of them are for linux. If anybody have script to export files to windows, kindly share.

I am using something like this for linux. the same or better one i need for windows.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/subversion-export-changed-files-cli/

Comment: 'svn export'? 0_o What exactly do you look for?

Comment: you can have bash in Windows, BTW

Answer (score 1):

- If you install Ruby, use [ExportRevs](http://kurakin.info/files/exportrevs.zip) Ruby-script, or ask to compile it into exe with ruby2exe or [OCRA](http://ocra.rubyforge.org/)
- In case of Windows, nothing will prevent to install TortoiseSVN and export revision-ranges by [GUI-way](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/tortoisesvn-exporting-changed-files/) (you have to ask question in more transparent style)